# Reuse value from parent object to construct child when deserializing with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I have two classes with a redundant shared attribute:

```
class Parent {
   int version;
   Child child;
}

class Child {
   int version;
   String name;
}
```

The `version` field from `Child` is just a local copy of the `Parent`'s own field, so it is represented like this in JSON:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "child": {
        "name": "john"
    }
}
```

I want to deserialize this JSON payload to the corresponding `Parent` object with `parent.child.version == 2` (the value is copied from the parent). How can I achieve this?

I thought about using `@JacksonInject` to pass the `version` to the `Child`, but that requires populating the injected values while deserializing the parent object. I could not find any way to register an injected value in a custom deserializer: the [findInjectableValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext.html#findInjectableValue(java.lang.Object,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanProperty,%20java.lang.Object)http://) method of `DeserializationContext` only lets us look up such a value.

Comment: Your `JSON` is incomplete. Please edit the question.

Comment: @Luiggi - It *was* incomplete before. Only opening `{` brace was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a Jackson-specific solution but it's probably the simplest one: create a `PreChild` class whose attributes match the JSON payload, then convert the `PreChild` to a `Child` in the constructor of `Parent`.

```
class PreChild {
   String name;

   public Child withVersion(int version) {
        return Child(version, name);
   }
}
class Parent {
   int version;
   Child child;

   @JsonCreator
   Parent(
       @JsonProperty("version") int version,
       @JsonProperty("child") PreChild preChild) {
       this.version = version;
       this.child = preChild.withVersion(version);
   }
}
```